# Is there is any way to show a processing message, then call a server side method using ajax and based on the result causes a post back

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a asp.net button on a page, when user clicks on it a message will be displayed first ("processing..") and then I am calling some server side code using ajax to perform some operation and based on the value returned by the server side method I want to perform postback event.

Comment: I have answered this a few times - have a look at it here (don't do iframe, it's really clunky) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068200/how-to-update-a-status-label-inside-ajax-request/13087734#13087734

Comment: Sorry I haven't mentioned, I am using .net framework 2.0

Comment: Doesn't matter - should be fine

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I also want to block the UI, Is there is any way?

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time - the process takes place in a iframe. As things progress a session variable is updated. PageMethods calling a Web Method is used in the page containing the iframe to query the value of the session variable  - and show the user progress - and, when the Session reports "Finished" - I click a button to cause a postback.

Comment: can you please elaborate it with an example

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery BlockUI. Its easy to use, see below example (http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
        $('#test').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: 'Please wait..', css: { width: '275px' } });
            $.ajax({
              url: 'test.html',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(e){
                setTimeout(function(){ $.unblockUI(); }
                  ,2000)
              },
              error: function(e){
                $.unblockUI(); 
              }
            }); 
        }); 

        $('#yes').click(function() { 
            // update the block message 
            $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Remote call in progress...</h1>" }); 

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'wait.php', 
                cache: false, 
                complete: function() { 
                    // unblock when remote call returns 
                    $.unblockUI(); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 

        $('#no').click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 
            return false; 
        }); 

    }); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<input id="test" type="submit" value="Show Dialog" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i am making synchronous call via ajax and based on the result my page will post back and block ui is not working with sync call